# What does this namespacing function in Javascript do?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading through the source code for the Rickshaw charting library and I found this fragment:

```
var Rickshaw = {

    namespace: function(namespace, obj) {

        var parts = namespace.split('.');

        var parent = Rickshaw;

        for(var i = 1, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
            var currentPart = parts[i];
            parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};
            parent = parent[currentPart];
        }
        return parent;
    },
    ...
```

Now I understand that this is the Object Literal Notation for namespacing.

Later on, when individual 'modules' are defined, the following syntax is used:

```
Rickshaw.namespace('Rickshaw.Graph');

Rickshaw.Graph = function(args) {
...
```

Can somebody please explain to me what is happening here. Why do they need a `namespace` function when just writing the following is perfectly legal?:

```
Rickshaw.Graph = function(args) {
...
```

If I had to take a punt I'd guess it was so we can define something like:

`Rickshaw.Something.AnotherThing` without worrying if we'd defined `Rickshaw.Something` yet.

Is this good practice, is it common?

Comment: I agree with you on the latter. I would definitely do it since it saves lots of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that for `Rickshaw.Graph`, the `namespace` function call is unnecessary. However `namespace` functions of this sort are useful for deeper namespaces (`Rickshaw.Graph.Foo.Bar`), where the code defining `Rickshaw.Graph.Foo` may not have been loaded yet.

The `namespace` function call is still included for shallower namespaces by convention - it helps prevent an error where, if `Rickshaw.Graph` was being refactored to be called `Rickshaw.Display.Graph`, then the person making the change will see the `namespace` call and update it, instead of having to remember to add it.

For your final question (is it common) - its hard to say. Many projects don't have so many distinct components that these deep, Java-style namespacing is necessary. The idea is definitely present in more than just Rickshaw though - ExtJS for example has `Ext.ns()` which does the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

`Rickshaw.Something.AnotherThing` will TypeError since you havent defined 'Something' yet.

You'd need to do something like

```
if (typeof Rickshow !== "undefined" && Rickshow !== null) {
  Rickshow;
} else {
  if (Rickshow.Something == null) {
   Rickshow.Something = {};
  }
};
Rickshow.Something.AnotherThing = {};
```

This namespace function is probably just a helper to prevent you from having to write the above.